# C# Tcpclient Client Send Message To Another client

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I'm developing a console App that allow Client To send a string to another Client.
Here is the brief of my current requirement
1.) Multiple TcpClient connect to my server using multithread. (Done)
2.) Updating DataBase When Connected. (Done)
2.) Echo message to Client. (Done)
3.) forward message from Client A to Target Client B. Client A need To Pass in 2 parameter which is Message and Target Client Name and i will search in database for IP Address And Port (stucking)

now I'm stucking in forwarding the message to client B which return Error:

> "The Request Address Is Not valid In Its Context".

Here is My Code For Sending Message. Function is call within Client A thread.

```
static bool SendTargetMessage(CommandJson commandJson, Machine machine)
        {
            try
            {

                IPAddress targetIP = IPAddress.Parse(machine.machineIP);
                int targetPort = Convert.ToInt32(machine.machinePort);
                Console.WriteLine("Target IP : " + targetIP.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Target Port : " + targetPort);
                IPEndPoint targetEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(targetIP, targetPort);
                TcpClient targetClient = new TcpClient(targetEndPoint);
```

`Console.WriteLine("LOL");
            if (targetClient.GetStream().CanWrite)
            {
                byte[] responseByte = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(commandJson));

                targetClient.GetStream().Write(responseByte, 0, responseByte.Length);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }`

Comment: Check the IP from `machine.machineIP`, maybe it has invalid IP. Also try to get the specific line at which error occurs.

Comment: the ip is correct, the error occur in TcpClient targetClient = new TcpClient(targetEndPoint);

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in

```
TcpClient targetClient = new TcpClient(targetEndPoint);
```

This overload of `TcpClient` constructor (`TcpClient(IPEndPoint)`)

> Initializes a new instance of the TcpClient class and binds it to the specified local endpoint.

So `targetEndPoint` should be *local* endpoint. You would need to use overload `TcpClient(String, Int32)` to connect to remote one

> Initializes a new instance of the TcpClient class and connects to the specified port on the specified host.

For more information see [TcpClient Class reference on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: i already solved the problem. i don't need to create a new connection to the target client because that required a listener on client side too, what i done is i store all available connection in a dictionary and i can use back the connection to forward message to target client. thanks for your reply. now im fixing another problem which is when sending too fast the sent data will join together and causing error.

Answer (score 0):

As @nikolaykondratyev has mentioned in the answer. You can use

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);
```

It takes two parameter-

- string server
- int port number

You might have to get a list of active TCP ports. Below is the command you can use in command prompt to get list of available ports.

```
netstat -a
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. The problem i already solved by adding all available connection in a dictionary and i can forward message to any connection inside the dictionary. now im fixing another problem which is when sending too fast the sent data will join together and causing error.